# Give more priority to a PubSubInboundChannelAdapter above all other channels

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

I subscribe to two channels. I use these as sort of a queue instead. I want to process the Channels.STORAGE_OBJECT_INPUT with high priority so the messages of Channels.MEDIA_RESIZE_INPUT should never stop the first channel.

Is it possible to always process all messages in Channels.STORAGE_OBJECT_INPUT first before going to Channels.MEDIA_RESIZE_INPUT?

```java
    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageMediaChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier(Channels.STORAGE_OBJECT_INPUT) MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate
    ) {
        return this.createMessageChannelAdapter(inputChannel, Channels.STORAGE_OBJECT_INPUT, pubSubTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageMediaResizeChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier(Channels.MEDIA_RESIZE_INPUT) MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate
    ) {
        return this.createMessageChannelAdapter(inputChannel, Channels.MEDIA_RESIZE_INPUT, pubSubTemplate);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Richard Lindhout, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Pub/Sub cannot prioritize messages. For your requirement, you can create a separate  topic and subscription for high priority messages, and another topic and subscription for bulk messages. Using this way the high priority stuff would be handled by not only a separate queue, but also by separate code, so there's less chance for bugs/stalls/starvations etc.

I would suggest you handle the high priority queue with separate code.